# RFID thread is not running in the background

Tags: java, multithreading, user-interface, javafx, rfid

I am developing a GUI program on JavaFX that runs on the main thread, there is also an RFID method that opens the reader to pick up data and this RFID method should be running in the background concurrently with GUI window. what's happening at the moment is the RFID method runs first until it's terminated (5 seconds) then the GUI runs right after that. So I tried to run the RFID method in a separate thread and put inside `run` method but there would be an error as shown:

```
    RFID rfid = new RFID(); // Error message : Default constructor cannot handle exception type PhidgetException thrown by implicit super constructor. Must define an explicit constructor
```

So I found out to fix that error I need to have a constructor,`(public MainController () { ... } )` and call `run` inside it but that doesn't actually help with anything. The GUI and RFID threads are still running separately one after another.

Any suggestions guys I would be thankful and appreciated a lot !

**MainController class :**

```
public class MainController extends Thread {
RFID rfid = new RFID();

public void run(){

    rfid.addTagListener(new RFIDTagListener() {
    public void onTag(RFIDTagEvent e) {

        try {
            ReaderNo = String.valueOf(rfid.getDeviceSerialNumber());
        } catch (PhidgetException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Reader serial number is " + ' '+ReaderNo);
        wallet walletData = new wallet("385055");   
        walletJson = gson.toJson(walletData);       

        String resultfromserver = sendToServer(walletJson); 
        System.out.println("DEBUG: data in json : " +resultfromserver);
        wallet  walletObject = gson.fromJson(resultfromserver, 
        wallet.class);                      
        System.out.println("DEBUG: The wallet's Data: "+' '+ walletObject);

        WalletName.setText(walletObject.getWalletName());
       }
     });

       rfid.addTagLostListener(new RFIDTagLostListener() {
      // What to do when a tag is lost
       public void onTagLost(RFIDTagLostEvent e) {
      // optional print, used as debug here
       System.out.println("DEBUG: Tag lost: " + e.getTag());
       }
     });

        try {
        rfid.open(50000);
        } catch (PhidgetException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
     }

        try {                                       
        System.out.println("\n\nGathering data for 15 seconds\n\n");
        Thread.sleep(15000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
      }

        try {
        rfid.close();
        } catch (PhidgetException e1) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e1.printStackTrace();
      }
 }

        public MainController() throws PhidgetException {
        run();
     }
   }
```

**Main class :**

```
        public class Main extends Application {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws PhidgetException {        
        launch(args);
        MainController object = new MainController(); 
        object.start(); 
          }
        }
```

Comment: Instead of creating the `RFID` instance in the constructor, you execute the whole logic on the thread creating the instance. Then you execute the whole logic again on a new thread using `start`. I'm not familiar with the api, but probably creating the instance either in the constructor or the `run` method and removing the call to `run()` from the constructor would fix the issue. Furthermore you'll have a much easier time communicating with the gui by treating the `start` (or the `init`) method as entry point and starting any background services from there...

Comment: Could you code those changes please because I didn't quite get you! @fabian

Comment: I won't write an answer for this question. I'm pretty sure assuming you know the basics the advice should be easy to apply: 1) Don't call `Thread.run` yourself 2) Move the constructor call for `RFID` either to the thread constructor or the `run` method depending on whether it's long-running or not 3) create/execute the thread from the `Application.start` method to make it easier to connect the logic to the gui (you still need to make sure the gui is not updated form a background thread (use `Platform.runLater`/`Task` or similar))

Comment: what is left then inside the constructor after removing `run` just nothing ! and if I chose to put the `RFID` to the thread constructor I wouldn't need to move it from its current position because it's not affecting anything, is it. so with considering that I have applied what you said and what's been changed is only the execution sequence of threads in which the GUI runs first then the `RFID` follows separately ! @fabian

Comment: `RFID rfid /*= new RFID()*/; ... public MainController() throws PhidgetException {
        this.rfid = nde RFID(); /* here exceptions are not a problem.*/ }`